# Getting MAX of a column and adding one more

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make an SQL query that returns the greatest number from a column and its respective id.
For more information I have two columns ID and NUMBER. Both of them have 2 entries and I want to get the highest number with the ID next to it. This is what I tried but didn't success.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(NUMBER) AS MAXNUMB
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID, MAXNUMB;
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that it just shows ALL the entries and if I add a "where" expression it just shows the same (all entries [ids+numbers]).

Pd.: Yes, I got what I wanted but only with one column (number) if I add another column (ID) to select it "brokes".

Comment: In Oracle DB ; `NUMBER` cannot be used as a column name. An alias already cannot be used within `GROUP BY` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  A_NUMBER
FROM TABLE1
WHERE A_NUMBER = (
  SELECT MAX(A_NUMBER)
  FROM TABLE1);
```

Presuming you want the IDs* of the row with the highest number (and not, instead, the highest number for *each* ID -- if IDs were not unique in your table, for example).

* there may be more than one ID returned if there are two or more IDs with equal maximum numbers

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan -- I have amended my answer although it remains in the question.

Comment: Thanks! This worked extremely well. Simple and to the point with a simple explanation. Marked as "Accepted"!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Select ID,maxNumber
From 
(
    SELECT 
    ID, 
    (Select Max(NUMBER) from Tmp where Id = t.Id) maxNumber
FROM 
    Tmp t
)T1
Group By ID,maxNumber
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The query you posted has an illegal column name (`number`) and is group by the alias for the max value, which is illegal and also doesn't make sense; and you can't include the unaliased `max()` within the group-by either. So it's likely you're actually doing something like:

```
select id, max(numb) as maxnumb
from table1
group by id;
```

which will give one row per ID, with the maximum `numb` (which is the new name I've made up for your numeric column) for each ID. Or as you said you get "ALL the entries" you might have `group by id, numb`, which would show all rows from the table (unless there are duplicate combinations).

To get the maximum `numb` and the corresponding `id` you could `group by id` only, order by descending `maxnumb`, and then return the first row only:

```
select id, max(numb) as maxnumb
from table1
group by id
order by maxnumb desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

If there are two ID with the same `maxnumb` then you would only get one of them - and which one is indeterminate unless you modify the `order by` - but in that case you might prefer to use `first 1 row with ties` to see them all.

You could achieve the same thing with a subquery and analytic function to generating a ranking, and have the outer query return the highest-ranking row(s):

```
select id, numb as maxnumb
from (
  select id, numb, dense_rank() over (order by numb desc) as rnk
  from table1
)
where rnk = 1
```

You could also use `keep` to get the same result as `first 1 row only`:

```
select max(id) keep (dense_rank last order by numb) as id, max(numb) as maxnumb
from table1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5SYKhOjW)